# How do I specify the proper timestamp in CSV format

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch 3.0.8 and running into a problem when trying to ingest CSV data using the org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper

The config file looks like this:

> ```
> <bean id="BMSDataItemReaderCSV" scope="step" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
> ```

```
    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters[bmsCSVFileInput]}" />

    <!-- Skip the header line -->
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <!-- split it -->
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="PROJ_TYP_CD, ...removed ... REFRESH_TMS" />
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="bmsContract" />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </property>
```

The BMSContract class has a field in question is defined like this:

> private java.sql.Date REFRESH_TMS;

The data file has the following CSV input:

> PROJ_TYP_CD,  ... '06-05-2018T01:02:08Z'

And here is the error message that I get:

> Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
>   Field error in object 'target' on field 'REFRESH_TMS': rejected value
>   []; codes
>   [typeMismatch.target.REFRESH_TMS,typeMismatch.REFRESH_TMS,typeMismatch.java.sql.Date,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [target.REFRESH_TMS,REFRESH_TMS]; arguments []; default message
>   [REFRESH_TMS]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of
>   type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property
>   'REFRESH_TMS'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.sql.Date' for property 'REFRESH_TMS': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found]

Comment: I tried with and without quotes (single, double, none)...  can't get it right.

Comment: I've added an overload method in the BMSContract object, thinking it may call that method instead:
``` 
public void setREFRESH_TMS(String rEFRESH_TMS) {       
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

 }    
``` 
No luck

Comment: What is the root of the problem - is it because my BMSContract object's attribute is declared as java.sql.Date?